# How do I handle marker click on Arc Gis android?

Tags: android, kotlin, arcgis

I am using ArcGis beta version of ArcGis here is the dependency for ArcGis beta
`implementation "com.esri:arcgis-maps-kotlin:200.0.0-beta01"`

I have this code to show the marker with drawable icon

```
val graphicsOverlay = GraphicsOverlay()
    mapView.graphicsOverlays.add(graphicsOverlay)
    val point = Point(
        -110.80518769034454,
        39.01637367273824, SpatialReference.wgs84()
    )

    val bitmapDrawable: BitmapDrawable =
        ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_bridge_red) as BitmapDrawable

    val symbol: PictureMarkerSymbol = PictureMarkerSymbol(bitmapDrawable)
    symbol.height = 30f
    symbol.width = 30f
        val markerGraphic = Graphic(point, symbol)
    graphicsOverlay.graphics.add(markerGraphic)`
```

I have bunch of these marker and i want to show some view when user clicks these markers
How do i handle the click listener on this marker?

I have tried this code but it dose not success.

```
mapView.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
        val screenCoordinate = ScreenCoordinate(event.x.toDouble(), event.y.toDouble())
        val mapPoint = mapView.screenToLocation(screenCoordinate)?.let {
            if (it.spatialReference != mapView.map?.spatialReference) {
                mapView.map?.spatialReference?.let { it1 -> GeometryEngine.project(it, it1) }
            } else {
                it
            }
        }

        GlobalScope.launch {
         val result=   mapView.identifyGraphicsOverlay(graphicsOverlay,screenCoordinate, 30.0,true)
            loggerE("result:${result.isSuccess}")
        }
        true
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The com.arcgismaps.mapping.view.MapView has a default touch listener installed that exposes SharedFlows for responding to gestures such as single tap, and provides both the `ScreenCoordinate` representing the tap-point on the Screen and `Point` representing the point on the map in the correct spatial reference.

Instead of re-setting the onTouchListener, just collect on the [MapView.onSingleTapConfirmed](https://developers.arcgis.com/kotlin/api-reference/arcgis-maps-kotlin/com.arcgismaps.mapping.view/-map-view/on-single-tap-confirmed.html?query=open%20override%20val%20onSingleTapConfirmed:%20SharedFlow%3CSingleTapConfirmedEvent%3E) SharedFlow.

```
mapView.onSingleTapConfirmed.collect { screenCoordinate, mapPoint ->
    val result: Result<IdenitfyGraphicsOverlayResult>
        = mapView.identifyGraphicsOverlay(
              graphicsOverlay, 
              screenCoordinate, 
              30.0 ,
              true
          )
}
```